# How do I run multiple terraform commands at once?

Tags: terraform

Hashicorp have a docker image containing terraform available on docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform

I can mount my terraform project as a volume and run `terraform init` upon it:

`docker run -it -v $(PWD):/tmp terraform:light init /tmp`

However I can't run any other terraform command else because `terraform init` needs to be run first

`docker run -it -v $(PWD):/tmp terraform:light apply /tmp`

that command returns:

> Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
>   Reason: Could not satisfy plugin requirements.

Which makes sense.

Hence, how can I run multiple terraform commands? I want to run `init` followed by `apply`.

Comment: Why are you trying to run Terraform interactively via a Docker for each separate command?

Comment: I think its handy to be able to run something in a docker container so there's no need to install terraform on the host.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Is correct about best practices here. If this was a CI system executing Terraform inside a Docker agent, then this makes sense. Otherwise, Docker over a static linked binary executable incurs additional overhead and maintenance.

Comment: Well this is purely for internal demo purposes. I've built a simple terraform project that demos some key concepts and I want to make it simple for folks to clone the repo and run `terraform apply`. Everyone has docker installed, not everyone will have terraform, hence running inside a container is an easy way to run the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `terraform init` command initializes the current working directory for use with the given configuration directory. In this docker scenario, the given configuration directory is `/tmp` but the current working directory is a directory within the container itself, not exposed from the host.

Instead of passing a path to `terraform init`, you can use the `--workdir` (or `-w`) option to ensure that Terraform will use that mounted volume both as the working directory *and* the configuration directory, which is the most common and best-supported way to use Terraform:

```
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/tmp -w /tmp terraform:v0.12.3 init
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/tmp -w /tmp terraform:v0.12.3 apply
```

With that said, the primary `.zip` distribution archives of Terraform are just a single executable that should be easy to extract and run on most systems, so the extra complexity of using Docker may not be worthwhile unless you are integrating with some other system where using Docker is mandatory. Running the Terraform executable directly avoids the need to translate between two different filesystems and potentially (depending on your system configuration) two different operating systems, etc.

Comment: The solution with `--workdir` works great. Thx @martin-atkins. I have edited the docs on my demo to use this.

Answer (score 2):

Running `sh -c 'terraform init && terraform apply'` as the single command through Docker will do what you need. For your particular case, you will need to use the `--entrypoint` flag to override running `terraform` by default. Setting `--entrypoint=/bin/bash` should allow running arbitrary commands, assuming bash is available in the Docker container.

`terragrunt` can automatically do `terraform init` when needed, so that may be worth looking into.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. When I run your suggestion I only get back the output of running `terraform` (i.e. without any arguments). I assume this is because `terraform` is the entrypoint for the container (I think entrypoint is the correct nomenclature, I'm not hugely familiar with docker - hence why attempting what I'm attempting to do here). Not sure how i can override that entrypoint.

Comment: @jamiet I made an edit showing how to do the override.

Comment: brill, thank you, this got it done: `docker run --entrypoint=/bin/sh -it -v $(PWD):/tmp hashicorp/terraform:light -c 'cd /tmp && terraform init && terraform apply'`